# How to get a unique identifier for a window?

Tags: vim

I am trying to get some sort of unique identifier for a window, so that commands can be run against that window.

Ie, if i need to give that window focus.. or if i need to see the size of that window.. etc. The problem is currently it seems like the window number is used as this identifier, but this number potentially changes any time a new window is introduced.. It seems like it is an index count from left to right and top to bottom.. which puzzles me as to why that would be used as an identifier.

Seeing as i have no idea what the user may do to a layout.. how can i assure that when i assign a window a buffer, or get information about a window, that the i am actually getting information about the window i want?

Comment: Can you use buffer names instead of window identifiers for what you need?

Comment: Well for this first project, i am going to have to. But in general.. isn't the ability to script a layout import? Shouldn't a script be able to have control over a specific window? Maybe that window loads different buffers based on the users actions.. How is that done :/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Recent Vim versions have `win_getid()` function and `win_id2tabwin()` in place of the below `s:FindWinID`. Also `win_gotoid()` to just go to window with given identifier. Identifiers are maintained by Vim itself, so even opening window with e.g. `noautocmd wincmd s` will not be able to create a window without an identifier.

---

For older versions, you can use window variables to get such identifier:

```
" put unique window identifier into w:id variable
autocmd VimEnter,WinEnter * if !exists('w:id') | let w:id={expr_that_will_return_an_unique_identifier} | endif
```

This should mark all windows. Or, it is maybe better to mark only that windows which you want to use just after window creation. To find a window with id `abc` and then switch to it:

```
function s:FindWinID(id)
    for tabnr in range(1, tabpagenr('$'))
        for winnr in range(1, tabpagewinnr(tabnr, '$'))
            if gettabwinvar(tabnr, winnr, 'id') is a:id
                return [tabnr, winnr]
            endif
        endfor
    endfor
    return [0, 0]
endfunction
<...>
let [tabnr, winnr]=s:FindWinID('abc')
execute "tabnext" tabnr
execute winnr."wincmd w"
```

Comment: @OtisWright You clearly have something wrong, there is no variable `w` anywhere here.

Comment: @ZyX sorry to be more specific if I run `:let w:id={something}` if fails, so I tried just running `:echo w` my poor vim debugging skills.

Comment: @OtisWright It is not useful without a message with which it fails. In any case, what did you want by doing `:echo w`?

Comment: Hey @ZyX if I run `:let w:id=15 ` nothing happens the command just stays in the bar, I was trying to figure out what `w:id` was by using `:echo w`

Comment: @OtisWright It is simply assigning window variable. `w:` is a scope, while `echo w` is either `echo g:w` or `echo g:w`. Nothing is supposed to happen, this is simply creating a unique identifier.

Comment: Hey @ZyX Ah I see thank you! Out of curiosity would there be a way to do this on only one window as part of a key binding? Sorry for the newbie question

Comment: @OtisWright I do not understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hey @ZyX I am trying to do this: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7409/persistently-fix-the-height-of-a-split-in-vim

Comment: @OtisWright Just add `:let w:id = exists('w:id') ? w:id : IncrementingIDCounter()<CR>` before `i` if you want to mark window with an identifier (`IncrementingIDCounter()` is still a function you need to write, but it is trivial: just increment some `s:` variable and return it). But it is better to fix `'winfixheight'`: I do not see why terminal should be resized in your case. It is either Neovim or FZF bug.

Answer (score 5):

Simple version:

```
let l:current_window = win_getid()

... do something that alters the current window and/or tab and now i want to go back

call win_gotoid(l:current_window)
```

Complicated version:

```
let [l:current_window_tabnr, l:current_window_winnr] = win_id2tabwin(win_getid())

or

let l:current_window_tabnr = tabpagenr()
let l:current_window_winnr = winnr()

... do something that alters the current window and/or tab and now i want to go back

execute 'tabnext ' . l:current_window_tabnr
execute l:current_window_winnr . 'wincmd w'
```

> JonnyRaa: ...I found win_gotoid fails with an error message about winsize

This error message happens when you forget to put "call " in front of "win_gotoid(l:current_window)".
I know because i just made the same mistake :D

```
:win_gotoid(123)
E465: :winsize requires two number arguments
```

Should be:

```
:call win_gotoid(123)
```

Comment: interestingly I found `win_gotoid` fails with an error message about winsize... so I used your suggestion of `wincmd w` instead.  Thanks!

Comment: I found this error with `win_execute` without `call`!