# Need some help configuring Vim

Tags: vim

I'm new to Vim (almost new) and have some questions.

The problem came from the following:
I have NERDTree and MiniBufExplorer plugins (I like them very much!).
I have mapped <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> to show up MiniBufExplorer window.
So when I focus on tree window, then push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>, find a file I want and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the resulting file opens in tree window (which was previous one). So, I want to have a window with a specific Name/ID and tell MiniBufExplorer to always open buffers there. In most cases I don't use split windows so it would not be a problem for me to open buffers always in same window.

I have looked into manual of Vim but didn't found any reference to window's ID, so I wonder if there is a way to give an ID to window and then configure buffer explorer to always open buffers there.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Might be what you are looking for ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215163/how-to-get-a-unique-identifier-for-a-window

Comment: Might be what you are looking for ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215163/how-to-get-a-unique-identifier-for-a-window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a switch to tell MiniBufExplorer to try to open files in a buffer that is modifiable (that is to say, not NERDTree):

> let g:miniBufExplModSelTarget = 1

[Prevent opening files inside NERDTree or MiniBuffExplorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514172/prevent-opening-files-inside-nerdtree-or-minibuffexplorer/9986370#9986370)